# Importance of thickness of SiO2-substrate for observing graphene's monolayer

Tags: solid-state-physics, graphene, microscopy

I've discovered that one should use 300-nm-thick SiO2 substrate in order to effectively observe graphene's monolayer through optical microscope. If thickness differs even by 5%, i.e. 315 nm, then graphene's monolayer flakes become invisible when looked through the microscope. Why is that so?

Comment: It is a consequence of the light reflecting back from the clean silica surface. [This paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0705.0259.pdf) explains it in detail and provides a mathematical model of the phenomenon.